# Non-header anchor links

Tags: confluence, docusaurus

We are currently in the process of migration from Confluence to Docusaurus 2. And we have many [anchors](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf615/anchors-967337548.html) in Confluence that we cannot reproduce as links to the headers in Docusaurus. For example, we have an anchor link to a specific table row. What options do we have in Docusaurus to create anchor links?

I tried `<a id="..."/>` html tag to create anchors and it works except that it seems that navbar's height is not taken into account (even with `navbar: { hideOnScroll: true }`). For example, we have `Literals.md` page with the table inside:

```
|Name                              |Example |Class              |...
|----------------------------------|--------|-------------------|---
|<a id="strliteral"/>String literal|`'text'`|`STRING[N]`, `TEXT`|...
```

And after following the link `Literals.md#strliteral` the actual position is hidden by the navigation bar:

[image]

Is there any possibility to fix this issue with the navigation bar or to use something else to simulate the Confluence anchor feature?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to add a css class to the `custom.css` that takes the navigation bar into account

```
.lsdoc-anchor {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: calc(var(--ifm-navbar-height)*-1 - 0.5rem);
}
```

And use it within an html `<a>` tag when creating anchors

```
<a className="lsdoc-anchor" id="anchorid"/>
```